# Qual a vantagem de se utilzar Tag Helpers no ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor

Estou estudando o ASP.NET Core e me deparei com as *tag helpers* quando gerei o *scaffold* de uma *view*. Achei interessante a nova sintaxe, o código fica mais legível em alguns pontos, porém, a inclusão de mais uma DLL em todas as *views* que for usado as *tag helpers* não pode acabar pesando no projeto?

Quais outras vantagens ou desvantagens podem ser destacas em relação as *tag helpers*?

Obs.: Pesquisando um pouco no Google encontrei [este tópico na SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29005877/what-is-the-advantage-of-using-tag-helpers-in-asp-net-mvc-5), porém achei interessante manter a pergunta para haver uma discussão sobre o assunto em português.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Em geral esse peso extra não é significativo e no fundo se não usar o peso pode até ser maior em alguns casos.

A principal vantagem você já percebeu, é a legibilidade do código. Isto tem a ver com melhor abstração. Também ajuda estar encapsulado e ficar fácil mudar algum detalhe do código final HTML sem precisar mexer em todas as páginas. Ótimo para evoluir o HTML dentro de novos padrões e práticas. Lembre-se que o *tag helper* é um método, ele possui todos os benefícios deste elemento de construção de códigos.

A principal desvantagem é que se perde o controle do código a ser usado. Se o *helper* for muito específico ou muito geral, ele torna inútil pra maioria dos casos, então é difícil achar um equilíbrio do que por no código dele. Pra coisas simples é tranquilo usar. Algumas configurações são possíveis, ainda que limitadas, se o *helper* específico for construído pensando nisto. Apesar que isto pode começar complicar o código e mandar a legibilidade pro espaço.

Eles podem não interagir bem com todas as construções da *view*. Isto depende da qualidade do *helper*, mas não dá para fazer milagres.

Como todo recurso, se não souber usar adequadamente, saber usar a criatividade para que ele realmente seja útil, é melhor não usar. Claro que usar os já existentes não deve ser um problema, mas criar seus próprios *helpers* exige uma pouco de experiência para não cometer erros e diminuir a sua utilidade.

Lembra um pouco os [*web components*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).